# where java main method is defined at the starting time of below class or at middle of programme

Tags: java

For example in some Java programs we use main method at below the class
in some Java programs we use main method after at writing methods what is the difference?

Comment: There is no difference...

Comment: None. main is still the first method to be called.

Comment: then we use main method at always below the class or not?actually this is doubt for me

Comment: Its not making any sense, just important is it must be public static void main(String[] args){...} , no matter where you define it.

Comment: @OP, you can write anywhere in a class as you want (beginning, last, middle etc) but of-course not inside another method. Java compiler doesn't care where you write it :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference if we write main method first or last. All the java programs starts the execution from the main class and it is independent from position (first or last).

Comment: //first programme   class Sum
{
public static void main(String k[]){
int a=10,b=20,c;
c=a+b;
System.out.println("Sum: "+c);
}
}

Comment: ///second programme  public class Sathya {
 
int a=10,b=20;
int c;
void Add()
{
 c=a+b;
} 
void Display()
{

 System.out.println("sum="+c);
}
public static void main(String[] args){

  Sathya s= new Sathya();
  s.Add();
  s.Display();
}
}
what is the diif between this two programmes

Comment: do you want a sample program?

Comment: no no see second programme i can add main method at bottom of the class it get error y? that is my doubt

Comment: Both outputs are same. But the difference is in second method it create separate class for doing addition and create an object in main method thencall the method Display() to print output.

Comment: i know outputs are same..but what i m asking is i can write main method at bottom of the class or not?if i write in second programm..class Sathya{ public static void main(String[] args) it shows error y?this is my question sir

Comment: what is the error getting?

Comment: illegal start of expression void add() void display () shows like this

Comment: try this,    class Sathya
{
 int a=10,b=20,c;
 public void Add()
 {
  c=a+b;
 }
 public void Display()
 {
  System.out.println(c);
 }
 public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
 {
  Sathya s=new Sathya();
  s.Add();
  s.Display();
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

there is no different, but you have to put all methods in a class...

you can read the manual :-) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: //first programme class Sum { public static void main(String k[]){ int a=10,b=20,c; c=a+b; System.out.println("Sum: "+c); } }

Comment: ///second programme public class Sathya { int a=10,b=20; int c; void Add() { c=a+b; } void Display() { System.out.println("sum="+c); } public static void main(String[] args){ Sathya s= new Sathya(); s.Add(); s.Display(); } } what is the diif between this two programmes